# How to avoid complex execution flows in a flux application where a method dispatches multiple actions?

Tags: architecture, redux

I've noticed that the execution flow in a medium-sized flux application is extremely hard to follow if one method dispatches several actions.

Refreshing the mental model of a certain feature when coming back after a while is pretty time consuming.

I was wondering if any one has tips on how to structure an app with has a big set of actions calls going on?

Comment: I know this is more a high level architecture question, but I would love your advise.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad. Can you present a specific example that you find problematic?

Comment: Is this Flux or Redux? It seems unlikely one project would use both.

Comment: I agree that its very broad, and providing an example would help answering this. Though, as a notice, I've been working on small to medium sized projects with redux and rarely came to call more than 2 dispatches in a single method (like with api calls XY_BEGIN and XY_SUCCESS/XY_FAIL). Maybe you're designing your actions to be too atomic? A single action can easily make multiple changes to your state.

Comment: I try explaining it with an expample
@quamo you make a good point, indeed are some of my actions very atomic and I guess I have a hard time to decide when designing an action atomic (because I might need ) vs. more composing one with many changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should generally dispatch one action for each state change that would be appreciable to the user. For async actions, which might have optimistic update, loading state, error handling, or whatever else, there's one action for each of those. The action payload should carry whatever data the reducers need to react to, and then just add a `switch` case for each reducer that should care about that action. But it seems like it would be wasteful and confusing to dispatch multiple actions that would happen more or less simultaneously.

Comment: “But it seems like it would be wasteful and confusing to dispatch multiple actions that would happen more or less simultaneously.” Yes, except that you might want to orchestrate among actions differently depending on what the user is doing. This makes it necessary to have actions that are loosely coupled and can be composed in different combinations.

Comment: Isn't that what reducers are for? To me, actions are like the events in event sourcing, they are merely a record of what happened. It's up to the decoupled components of the rest of the system to react appropriately. But that's certainly open to various interpretations.

Comment: Reducers can't have side-effects, though. What part of the system dispatches the follow-on events? For example, the change a user just made invalidates the summary on a different part of the page. Many different actions may invalidate the summary. I think what I'm leaning toward is having the reducer set a “stale” flag to indicate the summary needs to be refreshed and then something independent looking out for that. (Where does that “watch” logic go, though?)

Comment: I'm not by computer for links, but there are a couple extensions of the Redux idea that take this into account. Redux-saga is a mature library for this, and there's a somewhat similar concept of Redux Reactions that was proposed in an issue on the Redux GitHub.